# Wordpress installed on a virtual machine and behind a reverse proxy is redirecting to the VM's IP address

Tags: redirect

I have set up wordpress about as well as I can. I have the site url and home configs changed appropriately, and https redirecting is working fine. The only thing that doesn't is links like https://example.com/wordpress/index.php/postname. When wordpress gets a link like this, it's doing a 301 redirect to https://192.168.122.172/wordpress/index.php/postname. This is pointing to an address only accessible to the VM host, so of course the redirect fails and the page content cannot be displayed at all.

Why is this occurring? Everywhere else, wordpress is using the appropriate https://example.com/wordpress urls, so why in this one case is it trying to redirect to 192.168.122.172?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this. Apparently going to `wp-includes/canonical.php` and changing the line `$redirect_url = apply_filters('redirect_canonical', $redirect_url, $requested_url);` to `$redirect_url = null;` fixes this behavior, though it's a unstable fix since it'll be overwritten by updates.

Why is this so hard to get working? Every other webserver software I've used has not had a problem with virtual machines behind reverse proxies.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the proper solution is to add *passHostHeader = true* to your Traefik's frontend config as you can see in details in https://superuser.com/questions/1457357/how-to-fix-wordpress-links-not-pointing-to-site-url-when-being-accessed-through/1457561

Comment: I'm not using Traefik, I'm using apache + a libvirt virtual machine.

Comment: I'm sorry. Your problem is so similar to mine that I imagined you were also using Traefik.

Anyway, I believe the proper solution to your issue involves managing to get proper headers reaching Wordpress so it can properly deal with internal redirection as your solution is basically disabling internal Wordpress redirection.

Which tool is responsable for directing HTTP(S) requests to the VM Wordpress in your setup?